# Select rows between two rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There's many answers to how to select rows where values in a column fits between two values, but I can't find how to select all rows between two rows. For instance, say I have a dataframe, with a column that identifies the start and end.

```py
data = {'record_id' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'some_data': ['semper', 'lectus', 'turpis', 'proin', 'justo', 'vitae', 'luctus', 'magna', 'non', 'vestibulum', 'nulla', 'erat', 'nisl', 'orci', 'curae', 'nam', 'aliquet', 'aliquam', 'cum', 'convallis'],
        'boundaries': [np.NaN, 'start', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'end', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 'start', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'end', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 'start', np.NaN, 'end', np.NaN, np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How do I return only the rows that fit between each sequence of `start` and `end` (included)? I was thinking of using `ffill()` if I can figure out how to propagate forward *only* that values `start` (until the next value is `end`), still leaving blank all rows between `end` and `start` (otherwise I don't know which occurrence of `end` I need to include in my filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code:

```
cond1 = df['boundaries'].ffill().eq('start')
cond2 = df['boundaries'].eq('end')
df[cond1|cond2]
```

`cond1` means start & between condition, `cond2` means end condition

output:

```
    record_id   some_data   boundaries
1   1           lectus      start
2   1           turpis      NaN
3   1           proin       NaN
4   1           justo       end
8   2           non         start
9   2           vestibulum  NaN
10  2           nulla       NaN
11  2           erat        end
15  3           nam         start
16  3           aliquet     NaN
17  3           aliquam     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want to achieve:

```
   record_id some_data boundaries
1          1    lectus      start
2          1    turpis        NaN
3          1     proin        NaN
4          1     justo        end
    record_id   some_data boundaries
8           2         non      start
9           2  vestibulum        NaN
10          2       nulla        NaN
11          2        erat        end
    record_id some_data boundaries
15          3       nam      start
16          3   aliquet        NaN
17          3   aliquam        end
```

If so try:

```py
start_idx = df[df['boundaries'] == 'start'].index
end_idx = df[df['boundaries'] == 'end'].index


for i, j in zip(start_idx, end_idx):
    row = df[i:j + 1]
    print(row)
```